# using beanshell pre processor i need to achieve 1 request 30 Ids

Tags: java, beanshell

My client asked for 1 thread I should generate 30ids with 1 request (splicing strings in Beanshell and looping 30 times)

I tried loop controller but I couldn't achieve the 1 thread 30 IDs with get API request

Response for 1 thread

```
{"code":"CMSI0000","message":"Success.","data":[{**"personId":"8a8782188a459e86018a67d58a5c2885"**,"companyId":"8a8782048a3bdd8b018a4e7d27076b79","firstName":"Curtis","lastName":"Ryan","personCode":"4795169616341","personType":"EMPLOYEE","createdAt":"2023-09-06 00:12:42","updatedAt":"2023-09-06 00:12:42","delayPassage":false,"disablePersonAccess":0,"isSuperUser":0,"credential":{"id":"8a8782678c7dcf3a018ca4caacb60023","credentialTypeId":"9","duress":false,"validType":0,"status":"ACTIVE","content":"5000491/applications/4e09841390344a64a9d56af6bc7749eb/219b0161-5ba9-4bad-9fc3-33822c28f561.jpg","companyId":"8a8782048a3bdd8b018a4e7d27076b79","bioType":9,"signatureVersion":"10.4","signatureIndex":1,"signatureNumber":1,"validFrom":"2022-09-17 00:00:00","weigandSiteCode":0,"createdAt":"2023-12-26 06:23:15","updatedAt":"2023-12-26 06:23:15"}},{"personId":"8a8782188a459e86018a67d58a5c2885","companyId":"8a8782048a3bdd8b018a4e7d27076b79","firstName":"Curtis","lastName":"Ryan","personCode":"4795169616341","personType":"EMPLOYEE","createdAt":"2023-09-06 00:12:42","updatedAt":"2023-09-06 00:12:42","delayPassage":false,"disablePersonAccess":0,"isSuperUser":0,"credential":{"id":"8a8782678c7dcf3a018ca4caaecb002e","credentialTypeId":"1","duress":false,"validType":0,"status":"ACTIVE","content":"5000491/applications/4e09841390344a64a9d56af6bc7749eb/e3c72802-3dbc-4ccd-b808-526c526f5261.jpg","companyId":"8a8782048a3bdd8b018a4e7d27076b79","bioType":1,"signatureVersion":"10.1","signatureIndex":1,"signatureNumber":1,"validFrom":"2022-09-17 00:00:00","validTo":"2024-09-17 00:00:00","weigandSiteCode":0,"createdAt":"2023-12-26 06:23:15","updatedAt":"2023-12-26 06:23:15"}},{"personId":"8a8782188a459e86018a67d58a5c2885","companyId":"8a8782048a3bdd8b018a4e7d27076b79","firstName":"Curtis","lastName":"Ryan","personCode":"4795169616341","personType":"EMPLOYEE","createdAt":"2023-09-06 00:12:42","updatedAt":"2023-09-06 00:12:42","delayPassage":false,"disablePersonAccess":0,"isSuperUser":0,"credential":{"id":"8a8782678c7dcf3a018ca4caaa530018","credentialTypeId":"100","duress":false,"cardNumber":"100000000","validType":0,"status":"ACTIVE","companyId":"8a8782048a3bdd8b018a4e7d27076b79","bioType":100,"signatureIndex":1,"signatureNumber":1,"validFrom":"2023-09-17 00:00:00","validTo":"2024-09-18 00:00:00","weigandSiteCode":0,"createdAt":"2023-12-26 06:23:14","updatedAt":"2023-12-26 06:23:14"}}]}
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Nobody knows what you're trying to do, or how you're currently doing it. It **sounds** like you're asking how to wait for multiple futures/promises/whatevers to be resolved before doing something else.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.